# Sheldon Axler 4.11: How to understand the proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble in understanding the proof of 4.11 in Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Edition). The Theorem is the following:

> 4.11 Each zero of a polynomial corresponds to a degree-1 factor
>
> Suppose $p\in\mathcal{P}(F)$ and $\lambda\in F$. Then $p(\lambda)=0$ if and only if there is a polynomial $q\in\mathcal{P}(F)$ such that
>
> $p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)$
>
> for every $z\in F$.

The second paragraph proof to prove "$p(\lambda)=0$  => $p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)$" given is the following:

> **Proof**
>
> ...
>
> To prove the other direction, suppose $p(\lambda)=0$. The polynomial $z-\lambda$ has degree 1.
>
> ...

I don't understand that sentence "The polynomial $z-\lambda$ has degree $1$".

Questions:

1. Since $\lambda\in F, z\in F$, Shouldn't the polynomial $z-\lambda$ have degree $0$?
2. Why does the polynomial $z-\lambda$ have degree $1$?

Comment: $z$ is the variable of the polynomial. $z-\lambda$ has degree $1$ in $z$.

Comment: There is a mild abuse of notation going on: when he uses the expression $z - \lambda$ in the beginning and says "for every $z \in F$", that expression is just a field element. However, when he uses the expression $z - \lambda$ with the qualifier "polynomial" before it, it is being thought of as an element of $\mathcal{P}(F)$ and $z$ is an indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo and ZeroXLR. Yes, I should think of $\lambda$ as the root and z as the variable of the polynomial here.